# Error: The bot's MSA appId or password is incorrect

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, bots, botframework

Hi I am working in Bot framework in that I am facing the issue when I am testing the bot in local bot emulator after publishing the bot in to azure, and in the bot emulator I am providing the published url and Microsoft appid and Microsoft secret in bot emulator. When I am connect to azure, it’s show the issue like below.

```
Command failed: 4294967295 System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Couldn't acquire lock, is another instance running at Squirrel.SingleGlobalInstance..ctor(String key, TimeSpan timeOut) at Squirrel.UpdateManager.<acquireUpdateLock>b__32_0() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Squirrel.UpdateManager.<CheckForUpdate>d__7.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Squirrel.Update.Program.<CheckForUpdate>d__8.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result() at Squirrel.Update.Program.executeCommandLine(String[] args) at Squirrel.Update.Program.main(String[] args) at Squirrel.Update.Program.Main(String[] args) ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Couldn't acquire lock, is another instance running at Squirrel.SingleGlobalInstance..ctor(String key, TimeSpan timeOut) at Squirrel.UpdateManager.<acquireUpdateLock>b__32_0() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Squirrel.UpdateManager.<CheckForUpdate>d__7.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Squirrel.Update.Program.<CheckForUpdate>d__8.MoveNext()<--- {}
```

POST 401 [conversationUpdate]

> POST 401 [conversationUpdate]
>
> Error: The bot's MSA appId or password is incorrect.
>
> Edit your bot's MSA info
>
> POST 401 [conversationUpdate]
>
> Error: The bot's MSA appId or password is incorrect.
>
> Edit your bot's MSA info

[image]

I removed the App Id and password and tried to run it locally then it’s working properly.

I researched around the internet and could not find any solutions that solves my problem. Please help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Because you are trying to access a Bot Service which is deployed on Azure on the emulator locally. Try removing the `MsAPPID` and `Password`. It will work. The emulator is meant to test the bots locally without deploying.

Comment: Give the endpoint as `http://localhost:3979/api/Messages` while testing locally and not the **Azure** endpoint.

Comment: How can I test my bot using published url in bot framework emulator

Comment: You can only test bots locally in the emulator, make changes and publish it again. When you make changes and publish it again, the changes will reflect in Azure.

Comment: You are just getting a HTTP 401 which is Unauthorized request. For debugging published bots, try using `ngrok`.

Comment: i am already tried using ngrok but its not working

Comment: Like I said, make changes to your bot locally, check all the flows and publish it again. All reflected changes will appear automatically.

Comment: I am already did the same things what you explain in the previous comments. But at that moment also i am getting like that what i am explain in the above.

Comment: Where you get MSA `MicrosoftAppId` and `MicrosoftAppPassword` ?

Comment: I am getting the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword  from BotFrameWork portal

Comment: Try updating your emulator as well as bot framework SDKs

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `http://localhost:3979/api/Messages` in your bot emulator but do not enter any kind of id and password and also remove it from your `web.config`

like this shown in below picture:

[image]
[image]

And hit ctrl+f5 and then try. It will start working on your local environment.

For remote debugging you need to use the ngork.

do let me know in case you need more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue with following way:

When the supported account types is set to single tenant, if you use a personal subscription instead of a Microsoft account, the Emulator would issue the error: The bot's Microsoft App ID or Microsoft App Password is incorrect..

Go AD Application registration : Select Authentication -> Supported Account Type -> Accounts in any organizational directory ( Any Azure AD Directory - Multitenant )

Check AD registration to see if the supported account types is set to Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, the emulator allows to test local bots only and won't work with published/hosted bots. For published, i am testing on Azure on directly through the "Test in Web Chat" feature